# Xcode 4 outputting files and reading from weird locations?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am working on a C++ project in Xcode. At first, I couldn't figure out where the logfile was being output to. I tried some of the tricks online where people suggested I add the specific output location with no luck.

So, in my HD/Users/ folder, the log is being output there. Furthermore, the files that need to be read can only be read from there.

My project and folder are on the desktop but it looks like it thinks I am using the Users/ folder.

I have no idea how to change this and cannot find the application build anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show some compiler log output.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi There is no output. It simply runs and then stops. It compiles correctly but I have no idea where the output goes to and why Users/<myname> is the output destination. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out where you may be writing your output file by right clicking on the executable (the file with the black square icon, given that the product of your project is a command-line tool) in the Products folder in the Navigation Area, and clicking "Show in Finder."